# NuGet - Add to favorites feature?

Tags: nuget

The Visual Studio Gallery has a feature "Add to favorites". This is a really useful feature!
E.g.: [NuGet Addon](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c?SRC=Home)

On the other side NuGet is a big part of Visual Studio and used nearly in every solution. Does anyone know if [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages) has such a feature? I don't can find any.

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you mean a feature where you can add a NuGet package to a list of favourites. This is not supported. The NuGet addin used to have a list of recently used packages but that was removed because I believe it was not frequently used.

There is a plan for [NuGet v3 to be able to support curated feeds](https://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/432758), which are subsets of the packages available on NuGet.org.

Otherwise you would need to setup your own curated feed and maintain it.

Comment: Yes, I mean such a feature.